How to handle refreshs of a huge data state correctly in React
I've got a large data for a planning which i've discribed like this in mongoDB :

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose

const ENUM_CATEGORIES = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'other']
const ENUM_EVENTS = ['eventA', 'eventB', 'eventC']

const sessionSchema = new Schema({
  value: String
  category: { type: String, enum: ENUM_CATEGORIES },
  event: { type: String, enum: ENUM_EVENTS },
})

const intervalSchema = new Schema({
  sessions: [sessionSchema],
})

const daySchema = new Schema({
  date: Date,
  intervals: [intervalSchema]
})

const DayModel = mongoose.model('Day', daySchema)

cosnt weekSchema = new Schema({
  days: [daySchema]
})

const WeekModel = mongoose.model('Week', weekSchema)


I would like to render it in React and be able to update some values without re-rendering all of them...
So far I've used context API but I've read that EACH consumer of the context could be re-rendered if data change... There's no check as shouldComponentUpdate with context consumption ?
Each session could be turned into some input field to edit the session.value inside.
For a better understanding please check this code sandbox. Watch the re-render logs : there is too much !
What would be the most efficient way to handle this nested state ? As for an edit to a child I don't want to re-render all the tree !
Should I sub-divise this state and have multiple contextProviders to prevent the "data" props drilling ? Then how to handle the initialisation of those contexts ?
// Something like this ? ... Seems overkill
<WeekProvider>
  <OnDayProvider>
    <OneIntervalProvider>
      <OneSessionProvider>
        <Session />
      </OneSessionProvider>
    </OneIntervalProvider>
  </OnDayProvider>
</WeekProvider>

